# How to get multi sub strings from String, Android/Java

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I know there are similar questions regarding to this. However, I tried many solutions and it just does not work for me.

I need help to extract multiple substrings from a string:

```
String content = "Ben Conan General Manager 90010021 benconan@gmail.com";
```

**Note: The content in the String may not be always in this format, it may be all jumbled up.**

I want to extract the phone number and email like below:

**1. 90010021**

**2. benconan@gmail.com**

In my project, I was trying to get this result and then display it into 2 different EditText.
I have tried using pattern and matcher class but it did not work.

I can provide my codes here if requested, please help me ~

--------------------EDIT---------------------

Below is my current method which only take out the email address:

```
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN =
            "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
                        "\\@" +
                        "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
                        "(" +
                            "\\." +
                            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
                        ")+";



public String EmailValidator(String email) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

        if (matcher.find()) {

            return email.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());

        } else {

            // TODO handle condition when input doesn't have an email address

        }

        return email;
    }
```

Comment: split string using comma

Comment: @Vivek Mishra Hi, the text does not necessary has the commas. I just place it there for easier viewing. I have a regex formula for email and phone tho, but its not working:) Will remove the commas now

Comment: then use space to separate it

Comment: String s = Ben Conan General Manager.split(""));                                String s1 = 90010021.split(""));                                                                     String s2 = benconan@gmail.com.split(""));   Now use your s1 & s2

Comment: @AmarbirSingh have you seen what you have posted?

Answer (score 2):

You can separate your string into arraylist like this

```
    String str = "Ben Conan, General Manager, 90010021, benconan@gmail.com";
List<String> List = Arrays.asList(str.split(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.split(...)` is a java method for that.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
String content = "Ben Conan, General Manager, 90010021, benconan@gmail.com";
String[] selection = content.split(",");
System.out.println(selection[0]);
System.out.println(selection[3]);
```

**BUT** if you want to do a Regex then take a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16053961/982161

Comment: Hi, the text does not necessary has the commas. I just place it there for easier viewing. Sorry for the confusion. I have regex formula for email and phone, but its not working :(

Comment: ummm...place the right string so I can suggest something that works,

Comment: Hi , sorry for the confusion, I have updated my answer :)

Comment: @MattDonalds, ok tnxs, take a look at my updated answer please

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should do this instead of yours :

```
String[] Stringnames = new String[5]

Stringnames [0] = "your phonenumber"
Stringnames[1] = "your email"

System.out.println(stringnames)
```

Or :

```
String[] Stringnames = new String[2]
String[] Stringnames = {"yournumber","your phonenumber"};
```

System.out.println(stringnames [1]);

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex for phone number

```
[\d+]{8}  ---> 8 represents number of digits in phone number
```

You can use

```
[\d+]{8,} ---> if you want the number of more than 8 digits
```

Use appropriate JAVA functions for matching. You can try the results here
http://regexr.com/

For email, it depends whether the format is simple or complicated. There is a good explanation here

http://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html